# Unable to setup property in constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given the following Typescript:

```
class Tester{
    constructor(data){      
        this.Data = data;
    }
}
```

which generates the following Javascript:

```
var Tester = (function () {
    function Tester(data) {
        this.Data = data;
    }
    return Tester;
})();
```

Are there any reasons why the Typescript is invalid when the resulting Javascript appears to be valid (and works)?

[image: JS Output]

[Typescript Playground Version](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=%0A%0Aclass%20Tester%7B%0A%09%0A%09constructor(data)%7B%0A%09%09%0A%09%09this.Data%20%3D%20data%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%7D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your "Data" member to your class :

```
class Tester {
    public Data: string;

    constructor(data) {
        this.Data = data;
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

There is a shorter way to define class members :

```
class Tester {
    constructor(private data: string) {
         // this constructor signature defines a private member for the class 
         // and initializes it upon the constructor being called with a parameter.
    }

    getData(): string {
         return this.data;
    }
}
```

http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=%0A%0Aclass%20Tester%7B%0A%09%0A%09constructor%28data%29%7B%0A%09%09%0A%09%09this.Data%20%3D%20data%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%7D

Comment: Thanks, got that soon after. Just seems a bit strange at first.

Comment: Well it's strongly-typed OOP :P

Comment: If you want a public property specified in the constructor, you can do this: http://goo.gl/xv0gBP

Comment: ...you can even define private members that way! I'll update my question to reflect the shorter method...